# Concurrent in Python 2

Tags: concurrency, multiprocessing

I have a function `pre_raw()` and pandas data `train_raw.values` in python3 I could like this:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
     executor.map(pre_raw, train_raw.values)
```

How to wrote it on Python2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procs=[]
for val in train_raw.values:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=pre_raw, args=(val,))
    procs.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in procs:
    p.join()
```