# Is there a python 2 backport for the concurrency.futures package from python 3

Tags: python-2.7, concurrency, backport

I would like to use the nice executors and threadpooling APIs but I am constrained to a Python 2 environment. I cannot upgrade to Python 3 due to another third party dependency.

The closest answer I found is:
[Concurrent in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620692/concurrent-in-python-2)

Answer (score 2):

Found the following package for Python 2: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures

It says: Backport of the concurrent.futures package from Python 3.2

Trying it out.

Comment: I used that for python 2.7.  Installed it (i.e. python-concurrent.futures) using Synaptic Package Manager (for ubuntu user) instead.